# How do I install Orange 3 via Anaconda Navigator/ via Anaconda prompt?

Tags: orange

I downloaded Anaconda from their official website and I need to install Orange 3 in one of my environments only, so I did it via the Anaconda navigator, but it has been loading for hours. How do I know that the system is not hanging?

I tried another method on another laptop, to do it via Anaconda prompt and following the instructions on the Orange 3 website, which is to run:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

followed by:

```
conda install pyqt
conda install orange3
```

However, after hours I see the prompt just going "solving environment: /" and it stays there.

I have also tried running `conda install -c "conda-forge/label/gcc7" orange3` as recommended, but it also did not work. It just shows "solving environment: /" and it stays there for hours.

How do I solve this problem?